# "All of us had a good 'time' or good 'times' "?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which sentence is correct?

> **All** of us had a good **time.**

or

> **All** of us had good **times.**

"All" is more than one people, so I was wondering if "time" should be plural as well.

Comment: ***Have a good time*** is an idiomatic expression meaning: 
*Enjoy oneself,* as in
*I hope you have a good time at the beach.* so, "All of us had a good time".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which option is correct depends on the context, but the short answer is that it doesn't matter that *we* is plural, it matters whether there were *multiple good times* or not. There is some wiggle room with it, and in some cases you can use either interchangeably, but following this rule will give you a natural sounding sentence 99% of the time.

For example, if my friends and I all went to a concert together, I would say that we all had *a good time*, even though there were many of us.

> We had a good time at the concert.
>
> They went shopping, and all had a good time.
>
> I had a good time relaxing by the pool.

Alternatively, if I was remembering the summer camp I went to every year as a child I would be more likely to say that I had *good times* there, even though I am only one person.

> I had good times at camp.
>
> We had good times on our road trip.
>
> Remember rooming together at college? Those were good times.

Answer (score 2):

The two sentences mean different things.

"All of us had a good time." implies a specific occasion, whether on a holiday or at a party or on a cruise.

"All of us had good times." implies a much longer period, such as: "when we were young" or "during our school days."

Thus "time" can be either singular or plural, depending on the context.

Answer (score -1):

For OP's *specific* context, only the singular is idiomatically acceptable. Semantically it's possible to imagine that each of us had our own particular *kind* of good time (perhaps there was a party; some people enjoyed getting drunk, some enjoyed the food, some liked the music, etc.). But we use the singular because they all enjoyed themselves at the ***same*** place and time.

On the other hand, it's quite possible to say, for example,...

> *We've all had problems. But we've [all had good times](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22have%20all%20had%20good%20times%22) too*.

...where the plural is perfectly natural because those good times occurred on *different* occasions. It's just about possible to impose that meaning on OP's example, but idiomatically almost all native speakers would probably switch to Present Perfect for that sense: *All of us **have** had good times*.